# Change number of posts to display in category page

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently by default Wordpress display 8 posts in category.php page, i need to increase or decrease limit.

How to get it?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the belonging [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and change the `posts_per_page`-parameter to your desired value. Alternatively you could also manipulate the data with a [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: I can't use WP_Query, because is default category template :(

Comment: You can use of course `query_posts` too, instead of `WP_Query`. :)

Comment: Please avoid using `query_posts`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the number of posts displayed on categories.

Example:

```
function wpse_modify_category_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    // Check we're on the frontend and modifying the main query.
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Change to 8 posts per page when viewing a category.
        if ( $query->is_category() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
        } 

    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_modify_category_posts_per_page' );
```

Here we begin by checking we're not in the admin and we're affecting the main query. Then we test whether we're viewing a category page.

If all of those tests are passed we use the set method to change the number of posts per page.

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score -2):

In your category.php file, before the `while` loop, add this

```
// Get the last 10 posts in the special_cat category.
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' ); ?>
```

Replace 10 with your desired number.

Comment: Adding this, the current category changes to other category and display other post, example Page: Category A, posts displayed: Category Z

Comment: How to search for categories in `query_posts` / `WP_Query` is documented at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: Use 
`if (is_category( )) {
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
query_posts( 'category_name='+$yourcat->slug+'&posts_per_page=10' );
 }` using `get_query_var` you can get current category page slug and use to rewrite the `query_posts`

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks pagination, the main query, reruns queries which slows your page (not good for SEO) and breaks stuff that plugins rely on